# Does healing from Fast Healing and Regeneration stack?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, healing, stacking

I have Fast Healing 14 (from level 14 Battle Oracle with Major Curse) and Regeneration 15 (from casting Regenerate on myself).

Does the healing from Fast Healing and Regeneration stack, resulting in me healing 29 Hit Points at the start of my turn?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

With healing, the only time effects don't stack is when they are from the [same source](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312). See the Duplicate Effects sidebar:

> When you’re affected by the same thing multiple times, only one instance applies, using the higher level of the effects, or the newer effect if the two are the same level. For example, if you were using mage armor and then cast it again, you’d still benefit from only one casting of that spell. Casting a spell again on the same target might get you a better duration or effect if it were cast at a higher level the second time, but otherwise doing so gives you no advantage.

Nothing about [Fast Healing and Regeneration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=796) countermands this, so there is no reason to think that different effects providing similar benefits wouldn't each do their thing.

Comment: Hmm, so "When you’re affected by the same thing multiple times, only one instance applies." Would this mean I can't actually apply Protection from Energy for three energies, since only the newest one would apply? Should this be a question, or does it already have an answer/is the answer obvious?

Comment: @Phoenices I'd ask it and find out. I know that my conclusion would be that it's multiple different effects (resist fire 5, resist cold 5....) but maybe not

Comment: @Phoenices they have the same source (= same spell), so I'd read it quite clearly as "no you can't"

Comment: Well I'll [ask it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195361/28326)